# binding data to form array in angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have created an angular 7 app that has the ability to add and remove the controls dynamically. However, I am not sure how to bind the data to the form.

In the code attached below, I am trying to add and remove websites.  I figured out the reason why the data was not getting bound to the UI elements. Websites under FirmDetails model is an array of objects. At the moment for testing, I have added websiteUrl: FirmDetails.Websites[0].WEBSITE_URL. What if I have more than one object. How do I bind then?

UI

```
 <div class="form-group row">
   <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-1 col-form-label header">Websites</label>
   <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="form-group row">
         <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="inputEmail">Website URL</label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="inputEmail">User Name</label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="inputEmail">Password</label>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div formArrayName="websites"
         *ngFor="let item of frmFirm.get('websites').controls; let i = index; let last = last">
         <div [formGroupName]="i">
            <div class="form-group row">
               <div class="col-md-3">
                  <input style="width:100%" formControlName="websiteUrl"
                     placeholder="Website Url">
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-3">
                  <input style="width:100%" formControlName="username" placeholder="User Name">
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-3">
                  <input style="width:100%" formControlName="password" placeholder="Password">
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-3">
                  <button (click)="removeWebsite()">Remove Website</button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <button (click)="addWebsite()">Add Website</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Component

```
import { Component, Injectable, NgZone, ViewEncapsulation, ViewChild, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FirmService } from '../services/firm.service';
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import { CommonDataService } from '../services/common.data.service';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { ListItem } from '../models/listItem';


@Component({
    selector: 'mgr-firm',
    templateUrl: './firm.component.html'
})

export class FirmComponent implements OnInit {
    private Error: string;
    public FirmDetails: any;
    public EditMode: boolean;
    public Editor = ClassicEditor;
    public EditorConfig: string;
    public events: string[] = [];
    @Input() FirmId: number;
    DateFoundedDate: Date;
    public frmFirm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder, private firmService: FirmService, private commonDataService: CommonDataService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.initializeFormModel();
        this.getFirmDetails();
    }


    initializeFormModel() {
        this.frmFirm = this._fb.group({
            firmName: [''],
            shortName: [''],
            alternateName: [''],
            dateFounded: [''],
            intraLinks: this._fb.array([
                this.createCredentials()
            ]),
            firmHistory: [''],
            People: [''],
            websites: this._fb.array([
                this.createWebsite()
            ]),
            addressess: this._fb.array([
                this.createAddress()
            ])
        });
    }

    // public addWebsite(): void {
    //     const websites = this.frmFirm.get('websites') as FormArray;
    //     websites.push(this._fb.control(''));
    //   }


    public addWebsite(): void {
        this.websites.push(this.createWebsite());
    }

    public removeWebsite(index: number): void {
        const websites = this.frmFirm.get('websites') as FormArray;
        websites.removeAt(index);
    }

    private createWebsite(): FormGroup {
        return this._fb.group({
            websiteUrl: [''],
            username: [''],
            password: ['']
        });
    }



    public addAddress(): void {
        this.addressess.push(this.createAddress());
    }

    public removeAddress(index: number): void {
        const addressess = this.frmFirm.get('addressess') as FormArray;
        addressess.removeAt(index);
    }

    private createAddress(): FormGroup {
        return this._fb.group({
            city: [''],
            street: [''],
            line2: [''],
            line3: [''],
            zipCode: [''],
            phone: ['']
        });
    }


    public addCredentials(): void {
        this.intraLinks.push(this.createCredentials());
    }

    public removeCredentials(index: number): void {
        const intraLinks = this.frmFirm.get('intraLinks') as FormArray;
        intraLinks.removeAt(index);
    }

    private createCredentials(): FormGroup {
        return this._fb.group({
            intraUsername: [''],
            intraPassword: ['']
        });
    }



    get websites(): FormArray {
        return <FormArray>this.frmFirm.get('websites');
    }

    get addressess(): FormArray {
        return <FormArray>this.frmFirm.get('addressess');
    }

    get intraLinks(): FormArray {
        return <FormArray>this.frmFirm.get('intraLinks');
    }

    get cities(): ListItem[] {
        return JSON.parse(this.FirmDetails.LongCitiesJson).map(x => new ListItem(x.CITY_ID, x.CITY_NAME, null));
    }

    setFormValues(FirmDetails: any) {
        this.frmFirm.patchValue({
            firmName: FirmDetails.Firm.NAME,
            shortName: FirmDetails.Firm.SHORT_NAME,
            alternateName: FirmDetails.Firm.ALTERNATE_NAME,
            dateFounded: this.getDate(FirmDetails.Firm.DATE_FOUNDED),
            firmHistory: FirmDetails.Firm.HISTORY_HTML,
            People: FirmDetails.People
        });
        const websiteGroup = this._fb.group({
            // websiteUrl: FirmDetails.Websites[0].WEBSITE_URL,
            // username: FirmDetails.Websites[0].USERNAME,
            // password: FirmDetails.Websites[0].PASSWORD
            websites: FirmDetails.Websites
        });
        this.frmFirm.setControl('websites', this._fb.array([websiteGroup]));
        const addressGroup = this._fb.group({
            city: this.FirmDetails.LongCitiesJson,
            addressess: FirmDetails.Addresses
            // street: FirmDetails.Firm.Addresses[0].LINE1,
            // line2: FirmDetails.Firm.Addresses[0].LINE2,
            // line3: FirmDetails.Firm.Addresses[0].LINE3,
            // zipCode: FirmDetails.Firm.Addresses[0].POSTAL_CODE,
            // phone: FirmDetails.Firm.Addresses[0].SWITCHBOARD_INT
        });
        this.frmFirm.setControl('addressess', this._fb.array([addressGroup]));
       const intraLinksGroup = this._fb.group({
            intraUsername: FirmDetails.Intralinks[2].USERNAME,
            intraPassword: FirmDetails.Intralinks[2].PASSWORD
        });
        this.frmFirm.setControl('intraLinks', this._fb.array([intraLinksGroup]));
    }


    getFirmDetails() {
        if (this.FirmId != null) {
            this.firmService.getFirmDetails(this.FirmId)
                .subscribe(data => {
                    this.FirmDetails = data;
                    this.setFormValues(this.FirmDetails);
                },
                    err => {
                        this.Error = 'An error has occurred. Please contact BSG';
                    },
                    () => {
                    });
        }
    }

    get dateFoundedDate(): string {
        const dateString = this.FirmDetails.Firm.DATE_FOUNDED;
        const results =parseInt(dateString.replace(/\/Date\(([0-9]+)[^+]\//i, "$1"));
        const date = new Date(results);
        const month = date.toLocaleString('en-us', { month: 'long' });
        return (month  + '-' + date.getFullYear());
    }

    private getDate(dateFounded: string): Date {
        const results =parseInt(dateFounded.replace(/\/Date\(([0-9]+)[^+]\//i, "$1"));
        const date = new Date(results);
        return new Date (date.getFullYear() + '-'  + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate());
    }

    saveManager() {
        this.firmService.createFirm(this.FirmDetails)
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.getFirmDetails();
                this.EditMode = !this.EditMode;
            },
                err => {
                    this.Error = 'An error has occurred. Please contact BSG';
                },
                () => {
                });
    }

    dateFoundedChanged(dateFoundedDate: Date) {
        this.DateFoundedDate = dateFoundedDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: No. If you see the setFormValues method, I have done websiteUrl: FirmDetails.Websites[0].WEBSITE_URL,. In my UI I am already looping through form control. How do I bind the formcontrol to the array. At the moment it is bound to specific array element

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the array of values using **patchValue** like this,

```
setFormValues(FirmDetails: any) {
            this.frmFirm.patchValue({
                firmName: FirmDetails.Firm.NAME,
                shortName: FirmDetails.Firm.SHORT_NAME,
                alternateName: FirmDetails.Firm.ALTERNATE_NAME,
                dateFounded: FirmDetails.Firm.DATE_FOUNDED,
                firmHistory: FirmDetails.Firm.HISTORY_HTML,
                People: FirmDetails.People,
                websites: FirmDetails.Websites
            });
    }
```

since, the `FirmDetails.Websites` value is an array the value will get binded if you do like the above method

> First you have to invoke the `initializeFormModel()` function and then
>   you have to invoke `getFirmDetails()` function in the `ngOnInit()` so
>   that the form gets initialized first and the value gets binded.

- **patchValue** can also be done for form array

Comment: So my question here is that if I do  websites: FirmDetails.Websites then how will my model look like. Will it be same with regards websites . Referring to the createWebsite() method. How will my model look like with respect to websites

Comment: when you have many objects it also gets binded as you are looping in the html

Comment: Currently myinitilize formmodel looks likes this  websites: this._fb.array([
                this.createWebsite()
            ])

Comment: What do I need to do here

Comment: Invoke the initializeFormModel() function first and then invoke the getFirmDetails() function in ngOnInit()

Comment: Thanks Siva, I have changed the order of the call as you pointed. I am getting error Cannot find control with path: 'websites -> 0 -> username' in the console . Same error with other fields under websites. Same issue with addresseses as well. Remember both these are part of form array. What is wrong here

Comment: Hi can you please update your code in stackblitz please